# Write data to RTC spare ram in Linux

Tags: linux, key, ram, real-time-clock

My plan is to store data anywhere on the system besides hard drives, and that data can remain there even if the system is powered off.

Most Real Time Clock chips have spare RAM that can be used by the user. Though it is a easy task on a microcontroller to address that RAM, how can i do it under Linux?. RTC RAM seems a nice choice for me, since it is battery-backed RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will help, but `/dev/nvram` might be what you want. You need [CONFIG_NVRAM](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NVRAM.html) set in your kernel config.